# Regex complete words pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to get patterns involving complete words, not pieces of words. 
E.g. `12345 [some word] 1234567 [some word] 123 1679`. Random text and the pattern appears again `1111 123 [word] 555`.

This should return

```
[[12345, 1234567, 123, 1679],[1111, 123, 555]]
```

I am only tolerating one word between the numbers otherwise the whole string would match.
Also note that it is important to capture that 2 matches were found and so a two-element list was returned.

I am running this in python3. 
I have tried:

```
\b(\d+)\b\s\b(\w+)?\b\s\b(\d+)\b
```

but I am not sure how to scale this to an unrestricted number of matches.

```
re.findall('\b(\d+)\b\s\b(\w+)?\b\s\b(\d+)\b', string)
```

This matches `[number] [word] [number]` but not any number that might follow with or without a word in between.

Comment: Please clarify your requirements, and provide a real life example with expected output. From what you have shown, you cannot rely on a single `re.findall` call.

Answer (score 1):

Are you expecting `re.findall()` to return a list of lists? It will only return a list - no matter what regex you use.

One approach is to split your input string into sentences and then loop through them

```py
import re
inputArray = re.split('<pattern>',inputText)
outputArray = []
for item in inputArray:
    outputArray.append(re.findall('\b(\d+)\b\s\b(\w+)?\b\s\b(\d+)\b', item))
```

> the trick is to find a `<pattern>` to split your input.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in one operation with the Python *re* engine.
But you could match the sequence with one match, then extract the
digits with another.

***This matches the sequence***

`r"(?<!\w)\d+(?:(?:[^\S\r\n]+[a-zA-Z](?:\w*[a-zA-Z])*)?[^\S\r\n]+\d+)*(?!\w)"`

https://regex101.com/r/73AYLU/1

Explained

```
 (?<! \w )                     # Not a word behind
 \d+                           # Many digits
 (?:                           # Optional word block
      (?:                           # Optional words
           [^\S\r\n]+                    # Horizontal whitespace
           [a-zA-Z]                      # Starts with a letter
           (?: \w* [a-zA-Z] )*           # Can be digits in middle, ends with a letter
      )?                            # End words, do once
      [^\S\r\n]+                    # Horizontal whitespace
      \d+                           # Many digits
 )*                            # End word block, do many times
 (?! \w )                      # Not a word ahead
```

---

***This gets the array of digits from the sequence matched above (use findall)***

`r"(?<!\S)(\d+)(?!\S)"`

https://regex101.com/r/BHov38/1

Explained

```
 (?<! \S )              # Whitespace boundary
 ( \d+ )                # (1)
 (?! \S )               # Whitespace boundary
```

Comment: A second regex.. brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit complicated, maybe this expression would be just something to look into:

```
(((\d+)\s*)*(?:\s*\[.*?\]\s*)((\d+)\s*)*)|([A-za-z\s]+)
```

and script the rest of the problem for a valid solution.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tc7VKW/1/)